# java.sql.SQLException: No database selected Exception when connecting via tomcat

Tags: hibernate, mariadb

I get following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
        ... 52 more
```

I use CentOS 7 with MariaDB (tomcat8 / java8). I've changed the default Port in the my.cnf of maria db, then -> this exception occured. I use hibernate and i have already changed the port in the hibernate.cfg.xml

Is it possible to connect to mysql via a different port? instead of 3306 or is this not recommended?

I've reverted to port 3306 (default) then i get following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 17,287 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like your jdbc url is incorrect, (missing database name in the connection string). It should be something like jdbc:mysql://localhost/<mysql db name>.

Comment: jdbc url is correct, database is set after localhost:3306/....
i've found following error in the catalina.out:  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003  

May a problem with the jdbc connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

the tomcat restart script (service) was the problem. may the restart of the server was not clean and the connection pool size exeeded.

Manually executed the shutdown.sh and the startup.sh - problem "solved".

Thank you!