# Spurious "No database selected" errors with Slick/Tomcat/MariaDB Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, slick, mariadb

We have an application built on

- Typesafe's Slick database query library v2.0
- BoneCP connection pool v0.8.0
- tomcat7
- MariaDB 5.5.33 with Galera Cluster

that runs successfully for up to ~48 hrs and then starts throwing `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected` errors. At that point, some (but not all) queries will start failing with this exception. The problem can be temporarily "fixed" by restarting tomcat.

The obvious source of a "No database selected" error is that the database schema name is not specified in the connection setup, however, the DB connection parameters are given once in the application config that gets loaded at start-up so if that was incorrect we would see this error immediately.

- The schema name is not modified programmatically after start-up.
- We don't open connections independent of the connection pool interface.
- We have been unable to replicate this error anywhere outside the
  production environment. Load appears to be a factor but it is unclear
  how.
- No particular query is associated with the error and examination of
  the MariaDB logs did not turn up anything interesting.
- We don't see other DB connection errors like timeouts or connections
  being unexpectedly closed.
- We also tried switching from BoneCP to HikariCP which had no effect.

Somehow the connection is "losing" the schema name or this error is masking some other condition. What could cause this to happen? What (reasonably) non-invasive logging or diagnostics could we run against our production environment to diagnose the issue?

Sample stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1199)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.execute(PreparedStatementHandle.java:140)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:38)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:64)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.firstOption(Invoker.scala:29)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.firstOption(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.first(Invoker.scala:36)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.first(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcExecutorComponent$QueryExecutorDef.run(JdbcExecutorComponent.scala:32)
---- SNIP ----
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How do you select the database?  Is it specified in the jdbcUrl of BoneCP?

Comment: Yes, the schema name is given in the JDBC URL property.

Comment: That is fine.  It might be because the connection pool size is exceeded : you have the same stack trace as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129984/java-sql-sqlexception-no-database-selected-exception-when-connecting-via-tomcat).